# Acceleration, deceleration, distance - calculating point of deceleration

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics, classical-mechanics

I'm working on game in space and I encounter problem that took me few hours to solve and I reached point when I think it would be easier to ask someone more clever, that trying to learn from beginning physics formulas from internet :)

1. I need to find formula for calculating point at given distance the body will need to start decelerating. I know acceleration(a=1m/s2), deceleration(d=2m/s2) and distance(s=100m) the body needs to travel. Initial velocity is 0, and final velocity is also 0. Body start to accelerate and at some point it needs to start decelerating. Acceleration & deceleration are const.

After what distance the body needs to start decelerating. What is formula for this i can use to calculate it.

2. Like above but additionally it needs some time (for example 2s) before it starts decelerating (time needed to rotate the ship before it starts decelerating with main thruster). In that time its not accelerating.

Every help is will be really appreciated :)

*Edit - i made some calculations based on what I've already found in other posts and ideas other showed me and was able to solve it on my own :), answer below*

$\displaystyle V_{i}$ - initial speed at start position (known)

$\displaystyle V_{f}$ - final speed at end position (destination) (known)

$\displaystyle a$ - acceleration of body (known)

$\displaystyle d$ - deceleration of body (known)

s - distance to travel (known)

$\displaystyle V_{x}$ - speed after we reach we need to decelerate (unknown)

$\displaystyle s_{dec}$ - distance after which we need to start decelerating  (unknown)

$\displaystyle s_{acc}$ - distance after which we need to start decelerating  (unknown)

$\displaystyle t_{acc}$ - time for which we accelerate  (unknown)

$\displaystyle t_{dec}$ - time for which we decelerate  (unknown)

Comment: Using some other answers in other question I figured it out at what speed i need to decelerate. I managed to get this: Vx(speed at which i need to start decelerating) Vi(initial speed - here 0 but I will keep this in formula, might use it) Vf(final speed after traveling given distance) Vx = sqareroot((2as + aVi^2 + dVf^2) / (Vi+Vf) ) How to change this to change from speed to distance body need to travel?

Comment: With the energy principle, if the acceleration and deceleration have the same absolute values, then the point at which you switch from accelerating to decelerating is **the halfway point**. Seems intuitive, no?

Comment: In that case its easy, and in that case there would be no question :) But here can be different acc/decc values, that why i need formula (for example ship can use vector thrusters which have less energy than main).

Comment: Well then, I assume that you know the acceleration time for the first part, right? If you also know the total distance, then the equation for the total distance is
$$
\text{distance} = \frac{1}{2}a_{\text{acc.}} t_{\text{acc.}}^2 + \frac{1}{2}a_{\text{dec.}} t_{\text{dec.}}^2
$$

Comment: I don't know acceleration/deceleration time - that is what i want to know. I know total distance, acc, decc. For how long(what distance) i need to acc and then decc?

Comment: But i can get first t(tacc) from my first formula, then rest should be easy. I'll try to count this and check.

Comment: I've added my calculation to this question in image, but can't solve it still :/

Comment: Thanks Matti P. - i went your direction and I think it work for first point (added my formula and results in question) :) Now I'm trying to add to this calculation time needed for rotation - but in that case i think I'll use your first idea and calculate halfway point. Acc will be same as Dec in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was able to calculate on my own :) Checked with few set of variables and it works for me :) Thanks Matti P. for showing direction.

**Answer for point 1**

$\displaystyle V_{i}$ - initial speed at start position (known)

$\displaystyle V_{f}$ - final speed at end position (destination) (known)

$\displaystyle a$ - acceleration of body (known)

$\displaystyle d$ - deceleration of body (known)

s - distance to travel (known)

$\displaystyle V_{x}$ - speed after we reach we need to decelerate (unknown)

$\displaystyle s_{dec}$ - distance after which we need to start decelerating \ (unknown)

$\displaystyle s_{acc}$ - distance after which we need to start decelerating \ (unknown)

$\displaystyle t_{acc}$ - time for which we accelerate \ (unknown)

$\displaystyle t_{dec}$ - time for which we decelerate \ (unknown)
\begin{equation*}
\end{equation*}
$ $
\begin{equation*}
a\ =\ \frac{V_{x} \ -\ V_{i} \ }{t_{acc}} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ d\ =\ \frac{V_{x} \ -\ V_{f} \ }{t_{dec}} \ \ \ 
\end{equation*}

(1)
\begin{equation}
t_{acc} \ =\ \frac{V_{x} \ -\ V_{i} \ }{a} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ t_{dec} \ =\ \frac{V_{x} \ -\ V_{f} \ }{d}
\end{equation}
(2)
\begin{equation}
s_{dec} \ =V_{f} \ *\ t_{dec} \ +\ \frac{1}{2} \ d\ *\ (t_{dec} )^{2\ } \ \ \ \ \ \ s_{acc} \ =V_{f} \ *\ t_{acc} +\ \frac{1}{2} \ a\ *\ (t_{acc} )^{2\ } \ \ \ \ \ 
\end{equation}

\begin{equation*}
s\ =\ \ s_{acc} \ +\ s_{dec} \ =V_{i} \ *\ t_{acc} +\ \frac{1}{2} \ a\ *\ (t_{acc} )^{2\ } \ +V_{f} \ *\ t_{dec} \ +\ \frac{1}{2} \ d\ *\ (t_{dec} )^{2\ } \ \ 
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
s\ =V_{i} \ *\ \frac{V_{x} \ -\ V_{i} \ }{a} \ +\ \frac{1}{2} \ a\ *\ \left(\frac{V_{x} \ -\ V_{i} \ }{a}\right)^{2} \ +\ V_{f} \ *\ \frac{V_{x} \ -\ V_{f} \ }{d} \ +\ \ \frac{1}{2} \ d\ *\ \left(\frac{V_{x} \ -\ V_{f} \ }{d}\right)^{2}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
s\ =\frac{V_{x} V_{i} \ -\ V^{2}_{i} \ }{a} \ +\ \ \frac{V^{2}_{x} \ -\ 2V_{x} V_{i} \ +\ V^{2}_{i} \ }{2\ a} +\frac{V_{x} V_{f} \ -V^{2}_{f} \ \ }{d} +\ \ \ \frac{{V^{2}_{x} \ -\ 2V_{x} V_{f} \ +\ V_{f}}^{2}}{2\ d}
\end{equation*}

\begin{gather*}
{2\ ads\ =2dV_{x} V_{i} \ -2dV^{2}_{i} \ +\ \ dV^{2}_{x} \ -\ 2dV_{x} V_{i} \ +\ dV^{2}_{i} \ +\ 2aV_{x} V_{f} \ \ -\ 2aV^{2}_{f} \ +\ aV^{2}_{x} \ -\ 2aV_{x} V_{f} \ +\ aV_{f}}^{2}\\
\end{gather*}
\begin{equation*}
{2\ ads\ =\ dV^{2}_{x} \ -\ dV^{2}_{i} \ +\ aV^{2}_{x} \ -\ aV_{f}}^{2}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
{2\ ads\ +\ aV_{f}}^{2} \ +\ dV^{2}_{i} \ =\ V^{2}_{x} \ ( d\ +\ a)
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\frac{{2\ ads\ +\ aV_{f}}^{2} \ +\ dV^{2}_{i}}{( d\ +\ a)} \ =\ V^{2}_{x} \ 
\end{equation*}
(3)
\begin{equation}
\sqrt{\frac{{2\ ads\ +\ aV_{f}}^{2} \ +\ dV^{2}_{i}}{( d\ +\ a)}} \ =\ V_{x} \ 
\end{equation}

When I get result of Vx I can get t needed for acceleration to Vx and deceleration from Vx (formula (1)). Then I can get distance s for acceleration by using formula (3), which is the value I needed.

**Answer for point 2**

$\displaystyle t_{rot}$ - time for rotation of body \ (known)

$\displaystyle t$ - time to travel given distance (we can get this from previous formula)

At this point we want to know how long body need to accelerate before it can rotate and then decelerate.

\begin{equation*}
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ t\ =\ \ t_{acc} \ +\ t_{dec} \ +t_{rot} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ t_{dec} \ =\ \ t_{acc}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ t\ =\ 2t_{acc} +t_{rot} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \frac{\ t\ -t_{rot}}{2} \ \ \ =\ t_{acc} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 
\end{equation*}